# Get running time of a thread java

Tags: java

How can I get the runtime a thread in java such as: at 00:30 minutes of Thread[n], something() happened.

I'm basically looking to make a log file for a program dealing with audio files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the `System.nanoTime()` in the beginning and then calculate the difference at the end. Then use `TimeUnit` to convert to a more useful unit.

Also check the [`ThreadMXBean`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) which is an MBean giving info about threads.

Comment: Okay, so I went using 'System.nanoTime()' & 'TimeUnit' . It is a bit more code than I expected, but it works smoothly, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can use System.currentTimeMillis()
Function to get the current time in milliseconds instead of nanos and then subtract to get the elapsed time